# Jquery - Use of $(this) in each

Tags: jquery, this, each

I'm french so excuse some translation mistakes...

I have a code, using Jquery and Ajax call, and i don't understand the following problem.

I have a table, with a first row.
At the end of the row, two option : Valid and delete. 
When you click on valid icon, a loading icon appear, a new row appear, append to the table, the loading icon disappear, and the delete icon is displaying.

When you click on delete icon,  it delete the row.

And so my problem...

At the beginning,  i implemented a "onclick=valid()" and "onclick="delete()" on icon directly.
But now, i find more clean to use a :

```
$('#valid'+i).click(function(){
    valid(i);
});
$('#delete'+i).click(function(){
    delete(i);
});
```

and the problem appear : When you click, for example on a delete icon line 3, it's the loading who appear on line 4 ...

There is the code

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
    include_once 'functions_sandbox.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Fonction qui charge les datepicker et les différentes options sur les champs
        function reload_jquery(){
            $('input[type=text][id*=tags]').each(function() {
                i = $(this).attr('num');
                $(this).css('border','thin blue solid');
                $('#valid'+i).click(function(){
                    valid_temps(i);
                });
                $('#delete'+i).click(function(){
                    delete_temps(i);
                });             
            });     
        }   
        function valid_temps(i){
            $('#loading'+i).show();
            $('#valid'+i).hide();
            var variables = 'mode=saisie_temps&j='+$('#j').val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    // Define AJAX properties.
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/dgi/ajax_sandbox.php",
                    data : variables,
                    dataType: "html",
                    timeout: 6000,

                    // Define the succss method.
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#data_retour').append(data);
                        $('#loading'+i).hide();
                        $('#delete'+i).show();                  
                        $('#j').val(parseInt($('#j').val())+1);
                        reload_jquery();
                    }
                }
            );      
        }
        function delete_temps(i){
            $('#loading'+i).show();
            $('#delete'+i).hide();
            $( "#confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:160,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Oui": function() {
                        supp_temps(i);
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Non": function() {
                        $('#loading'+i).hide();
                        $('#delete'+i).show();
                        $(this).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function supp_temps(i){
            $('#ligne'+i).hide('slow');
        }   

    $(function(){
        reload_jquery();
    });

    </script>
    <table id="data_retour" class="module">
        <?php echo ligne_saisie_sandbox(0); ?>
    </table>
    <div style="display:none" id="confirm" title="Confirmation">Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce temps ?</div> 
    <label>Indice J : </label>
    <input type="text" value="1" id="j" name="j" />
</body>
</html>
```

The "ligne_saisie_sandbox" function in 'functions_sandbox.php'

```
function ligne_saisie_sandbox($j){
    $retour = '
    <tr id="ligne'.$j.'">
        <td class="cellule _light">
            <label>Attraction'.$j.' : </label>
            <input type="text" id="tags'.$j.'" num="'.$j.'" />

            <img src="/dgi/img/b_save.png" alt="Valid" title="Valider votre temps" title="Valider le temps" id="valid'.$j.'" style="margin-top:5px;float:right">
            <img src="/dgi/img/b_empty.png" alt="Supprimer" title="Supprimer votre temps" title="Supprimer le temps" id="delete'.$j.'" style="margin-top:5px;float:right;display:none">
            <img src="/dgi/img/ajax_clock_small.gif" alt="Load" id="loading'.$j.'" style="margin-top:5px;float:right;display:none;" />
        </td>           
    </tr>'; 
    return $retour;
}
```

and the Ajax in "ajax_sandbox.php"

```
include_once 'functions_sandbox.php';
switch ($_POST['mode'])
{
    case "saisie_temps":
        $j = $_POST['j'];
        $retour = ligne_saisie_sandbox($j);
        echo $retour;
    break;
}
```

A little image to illustrate the problem

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises because you left out `var` on this line:

```
i = $(this).attr('num');
```

By leaving off `var`, you made `i` a global variable, which makes the `i`s in your callbacks (`delete_temps(i);`) all point to the global `i`, not to the local `i`.

Change that line to:

```
var i = $(this).attr('num');
```

And it should work. I'd also advise against using custom attributes. Use HTML5 `data-` attributes:

```
<input type="text" id="tags'.$j.'" data-num="'.$j.'" />
```

And use the `.data()` function:

```
var i = $(this).data('num');
```

Comment: Perfect ! I add "var" to my variable, i used HTML5 attribute, and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

What you experience is a common issue in JavaScript. It's a closure problem. You implicitly declare a variable called `i` in this line.

```
i = $(this).attr('num');
```

Since it's implicitly declared it's also global. That will result in each iteration of `.each()` uses the same variable.

In your case you have to options for how to solve it. Variables in JavaScript have function scope and since you never override the value of i you can simply declare the variable explicitly like so:

```
var i = $(this).attr('num');
```

It's generally recommended to declare variables explicitly and you can actually have most JS engines check this for you if you start you funciton like this

```
function(){
  "use strict";
  //...
}
```

The other option is a more general solution to this kind of closure problem. In this section
                $('#valid'+i).click(function(){
                    valid_temps(i);
                });
                $('#delete'+i).click(function(){
                    delete_temps(i);
                });

you can change it to

```
i = $(this).attr('num')       
(function(i){
  $('#valid'+i).click(function(){
      valid_temps(i);
  });
  $('#delete'+i).click(function(){
      delete_temps(i);
  });
})(i);
```

The difference is that in your code i is not evaluated until the method is called, giving you the value written to i in the last iteration of `.each()`. In the above code `i` in is evaluated immediately. 
As a simple example of the closure issue you are facing you could take this piece of code

```
var i,j, arr = [];

for(i=0;i<10;i += 1){
    //creates a function that closes over i
    arr[arr.length] = function(){console.log(i);}
}
for(j=0;j<10;j += 1){
   arr[j](); //They all output 9 to the console
}
```

changing the body of the first loop to

```
arr[arr.length] = (function(k){function(){console.log(k);}})(i);
```

results in the behavior that most would expect first hand, namely that 0..9 is outputted to the console

In your particular case simply declaring `i` locally is probably the most readable of the two options but it's good to know how to avoid closing over variables in general.